# What's the best way to store a binary tree on a server?

Tags: javascript, sql, serialization, binary-tree

I need to store a binary tree on my server in order to be available for all my users in their IOS / Android application.

What's the best (fastest) way to store it into my server ?

**Edit:** I need all my users can update a value in the tree. So I have my event in my cloud code.

1. Everytime my event is fired, I need to get the whole tree
2. Then I need to insert or remove a node from it
3. Save my tree somewhere on the server

Thanks,

Comment: Fastest to _save_, fastest to _retrieve_, fastest to _serialise_? More than one of these? Have you looked at any ways to store binary trees and if so did they not satisfy you?

Comment: Are you parsing the whole tree, IOW: do you want to view the whole tree at once.  If so a database isn't going to give you anything, and is likely to be slower.  But if you can view the tree in sections, then a database would be ideal, as with correct indexing, loading would be very fast.  As an example partial viewing might be (Bill Of Materials), that is a good example of storing in a database.

Answer (score 2):

Periodically, there are questions about how to *store* something in a database.  That is not the right question.

The right question is what is the best way to store something *given how you are going to use it*.  Your question has no information on what operations you want to perform on the binary tree.  Without that information, it is unreasonable to suggest any data structure.  There are actually many answers to your question, but not enough information to choose amongst them.

As examples:

- You could store the binary tree as a string or blob data structure in a single field, using application logic to parse it.
- You could store the binary tree using back references to parents.
- You could store the tree as nested sets.
- You could store the tree using full path references.

Comment: It isn't even close to being too long for a comment.

Comment: "The right question is what is the best way to store something given how you are going to use it. Your question has no information on what operations you want to perform on the binary tree. Without that information, it is unreasonable to suggest any data structure. There are actually many answers to your question, but not enough information to choose amongst them." this is your answer as a comment.